# Not able to identify Android request

Tags: android, django, http, android-asynctask

I have developed REST APIs using Django and I am not able to use session with an Android request. Each time it generates a new request from the same device that might be because of new Object of HttpURLConnection initialized in Async Task which django fails to recognise but that is not the case with Browser it works efficiently in that case.

What should be done? Should we add session id generated by Django to each header in request manually in Async Task or there is another way around?

Comment: You can use `Token` instead of `Session`

Comment: I am not using rest_framework, It's just a Django Project.